# Training letter images to a neural network with full-batch training

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

According to [this tutorial](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/)(Pure Python with NumPy), I want to build a simple(at simplest level for learning purpose) neural network(Perceptron) that can train to recognize "A" letter. In this tutorial, in the proposed example, they build a network that can learn "AND" logical operator. In this case, we have some inputs(4*3 Matrix) and one output(4*1 Matrix):

[image]

Each time we subtract output matrix with input matrix and calculate the error and updating rate and so on.

Now I want to give an image as an input, in this case, What will be my output? How can I define that image is an "A" letter? one solution is define "1" as  "A" letter and "0" for "non-A" , But if my output is a scalar, How can I subtract it with hidden layer and calculate error and update weights? This tutorial uses "full-batch" training and multiply whole input matrix with weight matrix. I want to do with this method. The final destination is designing a neural net that can recognize "A" letter in the simplest form. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist off: Great that you try to understand neural networks by programming them from scratch, instead of starting of with some complex library. Let me try to clear things up: your understanding here:

> Each time we subtract output matrix with input matrix and calculate the error and updating rate and so on.

is not really correct. In your example, the input matrix `X` is what you present to the input of your neural network. The output `Y` is what you want the network to do for `X`: the first element `Y[0]` is the desired output for the first row of `X`, and so on. We often call this the "target vector". Now to calculate the loss function (i.e. the error) we compare the output of the network (`L2` in the linked example code), to the target vector`Y`. In words, we compare what we *want* the network to do (`Y`) to what it *really* does (`L2`). Then we make one step towards a direction which is closer to `Y`.

Now, if you want to use an image as the input, you should think of each pixel in the image as one input variable. Previously, we had two input variables: A and B, for which we wanted to calculate the term X = A ∧ B.

**Example**:

If we take a 8-by-8 pixel image, we have 8*8=64 input variables. Thus, our input matrix `X` should be a matrix with 65 columns (the 64 pixels of the image + 1 input as bias term, which is constantly =1) and one row per training example you have. E.g. if you have one image of each of the 26 letters, the matrix will contain 26 rows.

The output (target) vector `Y` should have the same length as `X`, i.e. 26 in the previous example. Each element in `Y` is 1 if the corresponding input row is an A, and 0 if it is another letter. In our example, `Y[0]` would be 1, `Y[1:]` would be 0.

Now, you can use the same code as before: the output `L2` will be a vector containing the networks prediction, which you can then compare to `Y` as before.

**tl;dr** The key idea is to forget that an image is 2D, and store each input image as a vector.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Your last sentence saved me. "store each input image as a vector". 

I was thinking I have to use an image with the initial form. right now, if I convert it to a vector, I can design my model. 

thanks again.